# Windows の Neovim で外部コマンドの結果が文字化けする

Tags: windows, vim, neovim

Windows 10でNeovim (nvim-qt.exe)を実行し、`:Tutor`でチュートリアルを読んでいます。
バージョンは0.8.1です。

`:!ls`を実行する指示があったので実行したところ、結果が以下のように文字化けします。

```
'ls' <82> A<93> ...(以下続く)
```

おそらく、コマンドプロンプト上で`ls`を実行したときの、

```
'ls' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、
操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。
```

がshift-jisでない文字コードで表示されたのだろうと予想してます。
（`:!dir`でも、日本語だったであろう部分が化けることは変わりありませんでした。）

質問は2点あって、

1. 文字が正しく表示されるための方法はありますか？
2. `:!`によるコマンドがcmdでなくpwshで実行されるようにする方法はありますか？

です。

Comment: この辺で説明されている何かの設定が合っていないのでは？ [3.  エンコーディング (Encoding)](https://vim-jp.org/vimdoc-ja/mbyte.html#mbyte-locale), [エンコーディングの変換](https://vim-jp.org/vimdoc-ja/mbyte.html#charset-conversion), [termencoding](https://vim-jp.org/vimdoc-ja/options.html#'termencoding'), [【Windows10】NetVim環境を一から整える（with scoop）](https://qiita.com/koKekkoh/items/d030835cacda01eedab1) あるいはこちらのように明示的に変換を行うとか。[\[Win 7\] vimからneovimに乗り換える(Thu Oct 18, 2018)](http://mrymy.cocolog-nifty.com/blog/2018/11/win-7-vimneovim.html) `パイプコマンドを使って「:!dir | iconv -t utf-8」としたら 文字化けが解消した。`

Comment: よく理解できてませんが、とりあえず
①set termencoding=cp932
②set termencoding=utf-8
を順に試しましたが駄目でした。

:!dir | iconv -t utf-8 はwindowsにiconvが無いのでダメです。

Comment: `iconv`は紹介記事でも後からインストールしたと書かれています。他に`nkf`とかも有名でどちらか(どちらも？)インストールすれば良いのでは？

Comment: コマンドを打つたびに毎回必ずiconvやnkfを打たなければ行けないのは
現実的な解決策ではない気がします。（なにか勘違いしていたらすみません。）

Comment: まあ設定ファイル等で何とかなれば良かったのですが、その通りツールを使うのは解決策って訳ではありません。だから回答では無くコメントでの情報提供に留めています。あとは「ベータ」版的な扱いですが、OS全体をUTF-8に設定するオプションがあります。[Windows 10の文字コード（システムロケール）をUTF-8に変更する方法](https://togeonet.co.jp/post-13850) いずれはこちらが本命になっていくのかもしれませんね。

Comment: Windowsでneovimを使いたいだけというのであれば、WSL上でneovimを使った方が良いかもしれません。Windowsターミル＋WSL2＋Ubutuでのnvimなら文字化けはしませんでしたし、(日本語環境の設定が必要ですが)nvim-qtもシェルがWSL上のものになるので文字化けはしないようです。

Comment: WindowsだがMinGW64とvimという別の環境でのターミナル上での文字化けという類似問題を、iconvを呼び出すラッパースクリプトで解決した例のようです。何か参考になるかも。[git bash とvim ターミナル機能における環境設定ファイルの違い](https://qiita.com/masafullversion/items/651b7313ff7de5b4e6fe)

Answer (score 0):

部分回答、かつ実際に試したわけではありませんが、外部コマンドとして cmd の代わりに PowerShell を呼び出す方法については、以下のような方法が紹介されていました。

`pwsh.exe` (PowerShell Core) を呼び出すには `set shell=pwsh` に置き換えれば良さそうです。

[How do I make neovim use Powershell for external commands?](https://www.reddit.com/r/neovim/comments/vpnhrl/how_do_i_make_neovim_use_powershell_for_external/)

> You can paste these lines to your vimrc (vim: `C:\Users\<username>\_vimrc`, neovim: `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\nvim\init.vim`) to make the change permanent. (Reopen vim to apply it)
>
> ```
> set shell=powershell
> set shellcmdflag=-command
> set shellquote=\"
> set shellxquote=
> ```

Answer (score -1):

> :!によるコマンドがcmdでなくpwshで実行されるようにする方法はありますか？
> です。

neovimの変数shellにpowershellやpowershellのパス名を設定してみましたが、シェルをpowershellに変えることができませんでした。
※この方法がだめという意図はありません。私がやってみてダメだったというだけです。

どうしてもpowershellのコマンドを実行したい場合は

```
:!powershell pwd
```

のようにpowershellと実行するコマンドを指定すればよいようです。

[image]